# Deploying Rails and Nodejs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, heroku, haproxy

I wrote a real-time web app that consists of the following:

1. Rails to serve the web pages (listens on port 80)
2. Nodejs to handle real-time logic (listens to port 8888)

So on a particular page served by my rails app, the JS will use socket.io to establish a connection to my nodejs instance to allow real time http push.

Currently Nodejs communicates with Rails simply by updating the rails database. (I know this is **ghetto** but it works).

### What are my options for deployment?

1. I have deployed simple web apps on heroku before and I really like the simplicity.
2. I have also deployed a web app with similar functionality (except it's made up of django + nodejs). I used HAProxy to do reverse proxying to handle direction of traffic to the correct process on my machine. However, I deployed this on a VPS server instead.

*Note: the ugliness will probably revolve around:*

- I am relying on a common db
- These processes are listening on different ports

Comment: Get a VPS and install whatever you want on it?

Comment: You can run the Cedar version of Heroku, which lets you specify different processes to run under the same 'roof'. Have you looked into that?

Answer (score 1):

We had this exact issue. We deployed them to separate Heroku applications, but kept them within the same code base. http://techtime.getharvest.com/blog/deploying-multiple-heroku-apps-from-a-single-repo outlines how to do it.

1. [Manually set the buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#using-a-custom-buildpack)
2. Set [a config variable](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#setting-up-config-vars-for-a-deployed-application) that you can reuse in step #3.
3. Create a custom web script that your Procfile uses

A custom script in bin/web

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$RAILS_DEPLOYMENT" == "true" ]; then
  bundle exec rails server -p $PORT
else
  node node/index.js
fi
```

And the Procfile:

```
web: bin/web
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider setting these two applications up as separate Heroku applications on different subdomains and just having them both on port 80. The communication between them goes through a shared database so they don't need to reside on the same machine or even datacenter. Socket.io supports cross domain requests on all browsers, so that shouldn't cause any problems.